# CSS only parallax effect with translateZ not working on iOS Safari

Tags: css, parallax

Two HTML elements, header and main. When scrolling, the header is slower than the page flow.
This parallax effect is achieved with the CSS properties perspective / transform:translateZ.

According to caniuse.com, those properties should work not only on desktop browsers, but also on iOS safari - which they don't.

Why not?

```css
/*
    --perspective: 5px;
    --distance: -2px;
*/
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    perspective: 5px;
    perspective-origin: center top;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/1200/400);
    background-size: cover;
    /* (perspective — distance) / perspective = scaleFactor */
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale( calc(7 / 5));
    transform-origin: 50% top;
}

main {
    height: 200vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient( #ccf, #a00);
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header></header>
        <main>Lorem ipsum dolor<br> sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> Ea vero necessitatibus delectus<br>ullam hic! Aliquam voluptatem pariatur vero vel nesciunt, eius velit commodi labore voluptatibus amet quidem aspernatur itaque ad.</main>
    </div>
```

Comment: I enjoy how this example manages to leave the frame of the snippet `:-D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is duplicate of this one:
[CSS only Parallax Scrolling stoped working with IOS/PadOS13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409202/css-only-parallax-scrolling-stoped-working-with-ios-pados13)

BTW its because of IOS 13, *translateZ* does not work on it and there is no workaround. also seems its working again on IOS 14.

Comment: iOS is becoming the new IE with regards to web standards. Apple. Never leading.

Comment: I forgot about this question, could have answered it myself in the meantime. Anyway, thanks for rounding things up.